# Sampled the original values and convert it to no. of time it occured in sample

Tags: r

t has 20 values, c has also 20 values 0, 1. I am interested in t matrix. Here I have a Loop, repeating 5 times. Every time sel give 20 values. I want to store there frequency in t.mat. But how can I get the required results, the resulting table may look like the below table

`t <- 1:20`

```
#  c <- seq(0:1, 10)

t.mat  <- array(dim = c(20, 5))
```

`rep <- 5`

```
 for(mm in 1:rep){
 sel <- sample(1:20, replace = TRUE)  
 tt <- t[sel]
 #   cc <- c[sel]
 t.mat[, mm] = tt[1:20]   # here the problem lies, I have no clue how
```

`}`

The output for the above may be look like below. But t will be of 20 values, I roughly give just six lines:

```
   t   v1   v2  v3  v4  v5
   1    1   0   1   0   1
   2    0   0   2   0   1
   3    0   1   1   1   0
   4    1   1   0   0   1
   5    2   0   2   1   0
   6    0   0   0   1   2
```

Comment: it's not clear to me what you want to have in final matrix - give an example input and output (hint use `set.seed(1)` if you want to generate random numbers in a reproducible fashion)

Comment: This will not go well: `t.mat[20, mm] = tt[1:20]`. You are attempting to assign a 20 length vector to a single matrix location.

Comment: I want it step by step, as I need it further in my program. First produce WR sample of 20, transfer it to "t". Then matrix for this "t" with just frequencies of the values. Repeat the process 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a little bit as to what you want, but it's probably this:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(1:5, function(i)
  tabulate(sample(t, replace = T), nbins = 20)))
```

`sample` generates the samples you want, `tabulate` counts frequencies (with max specified manually as it will not always occur in sample), `lapply` iterates the procedure 5 times, and finally `do.call(cbind,` binds it all together by column.

Comment: +1 - slightly improved: `replicate(5, tabulate(sample(t, replace = T), nbins = length(t)))`

Comment: @flodel me thinks that's more than "slightly" :)

Comment: I like it also, thanks @eddi. But in this case I want it step by step. The Matrix is for one purpose and then the required sampling for other purposes, like censoring and for predictors.

Comment: @FazliRaziq I'm not sure I understand your comment - you can put whatever additional stuff you want inside the function in the `lapply` or `replicate` loop; fwiw your original code has two problems - it doesn't actually count frequencies, and the correct form of assignment in your case is `t.mat[,mm] = tt[1:20]`

Comment: Thanks @eddi for this correction. Do you have any idea for getting frequency for each value. Zero for not occurred, 1 for one time occurrence and so on for "1:20" values. Instead of values, frequency in front of every value. Thanks once again

Comment: eddi showed you to use `tabulate`. If you really want to keep your `for` loop, then do `t.mat[, mm] <- tabulate(tt, nbins = length(t))`

Comment: Thanks a lot @flodel. It is exactly which I am looking for. I am new to R, therefore it's very stressful. I spend whole day on it. Thanks

Comment: It's working only for integers but not for fraction values. In fraction case it only selects the integer part of it. Is there any way for fraction selection.    t.mat[, mm] <- tabulate(tt, nbins = length(t))

Comment: @FazliRaziq that's because tabulating doesn't make much sense outside of integers. I'd suggest either making your numbers integers (by multiplying by appropriate power of 10), or using smth like `cut` or `findInterval` to count frequencies in ranges; another option for "converting to integers" is doing `tabulate(as.factor(tt),...)`